# Why getApplicationContext and Activity context inflate different style of the spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-context

I have a strange problem. I have 2 pre-defined spinner in the xml. However, the item and related dropdown item are rendering in runtime.

However, the following 2 statement provide different result of the layout. I have no idea why the result is like this. But the main difference is `getApplicationContext()` and `this`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getSrvNumList());
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

[image: Normal layout]

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getSrvNumList());
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

[image: Strange text color]

Comment: Perhaps appcompatactivity (this) has the theme app compat. Your main applications theme is only used when you call getapplicationcontext

Comment: An Application `Context` doesn't really have a theme, even though you might set one on the `<application>` element. That just sets a default theme for the Activities.

Comment: The activity class is extended to FragmentActivity and there is no application theme in manfiest.xml. I want to know what is the default theme if I do not use application theme in manifest.xml

Comment: If you've also not specified a `theme` on the `<activity>`, it'd basically be whatever the manufacturer decided is the default for the device. If you're lucky, it's the standard for the API level; e.g., `Theme.Material` for >=21. That's kinda why you have control over theming your Activities; so it's not just whatever you end up with. Why are you trying to use `getApplicationContext()` there anyway?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for your reply. In fact, the founder of this project is not me. I saw there is strange result on this layout and wanted to fix it. Finally, I found the occurrence of this `getApplicationContext()` is almost seen in every Activity. I wanted to fix it first and now I want to change all to activity context. Setting Activity theme should be the better way to resolve the issue and for the maintainence

Comment: Yeah, you generally want to use the current `Activity` as the `Context` for anything `View`-related. I'm not sure why the original author would decide not to.

Answer (score 0):

As  @MikeM. commented, it is the issue about the context. Hope the following answer can help someone with this issue.

Use `Activity` context instead of `Application` context

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getSrvNumList());
```

Otherwise, the application will get different theme to render the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://medium.com/@gaurav.khanna/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22) (look for Chapter 3), we can consider 2 types of Context: UI-Context (for example `getActivity()`, `view.getContext()`...) and non-UI-Context (such as `getApplicationContext()`...).

When inflate view, let use UI-Context to keep its application theme. That rule is:

 `* Do you need to access UI related stuff? Use UI-Context.
 * Otherwise, Use Non-UI Context.`